# Magento 2: export products contains catalog price rules

Tags: magento

There's a way to export list of products contain also the catalog price rule?

[image]

By default export, csv contain the only standard price instead of price by rules defined in "Marketing" > "Catalog price rules"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it can be useful to someone else, I have solved by this query:

```
SELECT 
      DISTINCT cp.product_id, cpev.value, cpip.price, cpip.min_price, cpe.sku
FROM `m2_catalogrule_product` as cp 
INNER JOIN m2_catalog_product_entity_varchar as cpev 
      ON cp.product_id = cpev.entity_id
INNER JOIN m2_catalog_product_index_price as cpip 
      ON cpip.entity_id = cp.product_id
INNER JOIN m2_catalog_product_entity as cpe 
      ON cpe.entity_id = cp.product_id
GROUP BY cp.product_id
```